# Multi-output vs. multiple single-output neural networks for classification

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, classification

Is there a theoretical argument in favor of or against using a single multi-output NN to do multi-class classification vs. using several one-vs-all NNs ?

In both cases once all output values are obtained, the same decision rule is used: the output with highest activation "wins" and decides which class the prediction returns.

But I wonder whether -and why- it's better or worse to have all outputs calculated on the same NN rather than separately.

Comment: If you are interested in neural networks, you may consider joining the machine-learning site: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/41738/machine-learning

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Mostly I am against doing multiple classifications using the same neural network structure.  This is very uncommon in other AI constructs.  You don't do this with a Support Vector Machine, or Decision Tree.  I think that it somewhat muddles the problem.

The argument in favor of it is that your hidden layers are simply lower level feature detectors.  Your multiple classification (or regression too for that matter) output neurons are now independently using the lower-level features that your input and hidden layers are passing up.

I have not experimented with combining these into the same ANN vs separate.  My guess is that the degree of success will have to do with the similarity between what the multiple classifications are trying to accomplish.